# Accessing a variable in another object of the same class

Tags: java

I'm trying to access an array in the object "other," but I can't figure out how to access the variable. This is what I have so far:

```
public void union(DataSet other)
{  
  DataSet temp = new newdataexp();
  temp = other; 
}
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to access the variable, even when I create a method in the class that returns the variable and then trying to call it from this method union.

I have this method, and am trying to do: String[][] temp = other.getdata(), but the compiler says that it cannot find symbol: method getdata().

public String[][] getdata()
{

return filedata;

}

Comment: please read [Blocks ans Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html)

Comment: Creating a method that returns it should have worked. You should have posted that attempt, and then we could have explained why it didn't work.

Comment: When I tried to use the method that returned the variable, I got the error: cannot find symbol method data().

Comment: Again, I can't see why that wouldn't work. Sure it's the same file? Sure it's capitalised the same both times?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I good understand you question but to access a variable in another object of the same class just try this:

```
class MyClass {
   private int[] myArray = new int[10];

   public void myMethod(MyClass myClass) {
       // you can in this way:
       // int[] tempArray = myClass.myArray 
       // but this is better:
       int[] tempArray = myClass.getMyArray();
   }

   public int[] getMyArray() {
       return myArray;
   }

}
```

**Edited:**

But if you want to make union better extract union method outside class, create method:

```
public static MyObject union(MyObject myObjectFirst, MyObject myObjectSecond) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: That's confusing because you're creating an object and calling it "myClass". Beginners often get classes and objects mixed up so I'd avoid doing that in a code sample for a beginner.

Comment: public String[][] data()    {
   return this.filedata;
}  is what I had, I figured that would just return the variable from the class object that I wanted. However, it does not work.

Comment: @John I guess this is because you have getdata method in newdataexp class but you have in parameter's method the reference to DataSet (notice: you haven't such method in DataSet).

Comment: That's it, thank you! It was not in the interface I was using.

Comment: @smas how did you know that? Are you sitting next to john?

Comment: @Robin, I was beginner few years ago too

Comment: @Robin, this is because my English isn't excellent so I skip words like: probably, maybe, try

Answer (score 0):

replace datatype with String, int, etc for whtever the method returns.

```
datatype mynewdata = (datatype)other.getMeMyArray();
```